# How do I specify [isSorted = true] when using the .uniq function in lodash?

Tags: javascript, lodash

I have the following array:

```
var tst = 
[
 {"topicId":1,"subTopicId":1,"topicName":"a","subTopicName":"11"},
 {"topicId":1,"subTopicId":2,"topicName":"a","subTopicName":"22"},
 {"topicId":1,"subTopicId":3,"topicName":"a","subTopicName":"33"},
 {"topicId":2,"subTopicId":x,"topicName":"b","subTopicName":"xx"},
 {"topicId":3,"subTopicId":y,"topicName":"c","subTopicName":"yy"}
]
```

What I would like to do is to use the _.uniq function of _lodash

```
_.uniq(array, [isSorted=false], [callback=identity], [thisArg])
```

to create this:

```
var t = 
[
 {"topicId":1,"subTopicId":1,"topicName":"a","subTopicName":"11"},
 {"topicId":2,"subTopicId":x,"topicName":"b","subTopicName":"xx"},
 {"topicId":3,"subTopicId":y,"topicName":"c","subTopicName":"yy"}
]
```

I understand I can do this using something like the following but I am not sure I understand how this matches to the function definition I see in the documentation:

```
var t = _.uniq(tst, 'topicId');
```

But as my array is always sorted then how can I use the option [isSorted=true]. Also is 'topicId' 
considered as the argument to sort by?

Comment: Also from the documentation regarding the callback: *"The function called per iteration. If a property name or object is provided it will be used to create a ".pluck" or ".where" style callback, respectively."* Look at the examples, it's all there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have the answer in your question!
From: http://lodash.com/docs#uniq

```
_.uniq(array, [isSorted=false], [callback=identity], [thisArg])
```

So in your example, you would use it as follows:

```
var t = _.uniq(tst, true, 'topicId');
```

Comment: What is confusing me is. How does .uniq know which argument is which?

Comment: @Melina: It probably checks the data type of the arguments. Have a look at the source code (the docs link to the source as well): https://github.com/lodash/lodash/blob/2.4.1/dist/lodash.compat.js#L5332

Comment: As Felix noted, it checks the data type of the argument.

If it's a boolean, it knows you specified it, otherwise, it knows you omitted that argument.